# I Don't know how to google what I want: An equation of smaller increments?

Tags: algorithms

Appologies, I'm no mathematician, so I don't even know what words to google to find equations. This is likely simple math.

I need to create a formula in a program that for an input of 1 I can get a result, As an example 50, but for 2 I get a result approx 75, and 3 might be 95, etc, and I can structure it so the last result of 500 might result in 500. I'm sure this is simple, yet I don't know what its called to even google it.

Thanks in advance, I only need the name so I can google it, but will happily discuss further if interested.

Comment: You have to be more precise than that. You want a formula that sends 1 to "let's say" 50? What doe you mean let's say? what exactly do you want the formula to do?

Comment: There are infinitely many functions which pass through your desired points, but most of those aren't realistic to use or implement.  How exactly you want the function to act is entirely up to you.  Perhaps you might be interested in a "Piecewise defined function" and it be linear between each point, in a sort of "connect the dots" style.  If not, maybe you would be willing to have a function which is easy and passes *near* those points but not through them exactly, in which case you might be wanting to run some sort of regression, e.g. linear regression.

Comment: If your desired points are known and you want your function to pass through them: interpolation.
If your desired points are known and you are okay with your function passing near them rather than through: regression.
A function with smaller increments is ussually named "concave".

Comment: The examples of 50, 75, 95 etc are not in any way determined correctly, merely trying to give an example. I will have an input number which will create a second output number, which cannot be linear in growth, it increases but with smaller increments. I don't know the name of that, and its not linear.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a continuous function that "increases with smaller increments" for greater inputs?

A simple [exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_growth) function might fit your application:
[image]

The curve above is an arbitrarily picked exponential function that roughly matches the model you described:

$$y=-e^{\left(\frac{500-x}{80}\right)}+500$$

Since you said wanted a name that you can google, consider following up on the keywords

- Exponential Growth
- Exponential Decay
- Logistic Growth
- Polynomial Growth

Exponential models are trivial to incorporate into programs (the application you mentioned in your question). Most modern languages include built-in or library support for exponentiation. For instance, in Python you have the exponential operator `**` and the function `math.exp`. Java includes `java.lang.Math.{exp,pow}`, etc.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I always thought exponential was start small, get bigger at a fast rate of increase.

Comment: So, I googled your four terms and they do not show the pattern you displayed. Then I tried to put your given formula in, and nope, not even close. I tried with both x and e as the input, nada.

Comment: @BaneStar007 $e$ is Euler's number, not a variable. Any base will work, however. The model that I presented in my response is exponential growth with reflections across the $x$ and $y$ axis, which can be expressed by the general formula $y=-e^{-x}$. Try graphing this using an online graphing calculator like [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator). To tweak the model, use a formula that resembles $y=-e^{-(x-h)}+k$ where $h$ and $k$ are horizontal and vertical shifts, respectively. Note that  $y=k$ will a horizontal asymptote of the functions, meaning that $k$ will be the "maximum" output.

Comment: @BaneStar007 [Here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ceuvsxdfud) is the example model I gave in my answer in desmos, if helpful.